# 404 error when migrate from Tomcat to Glassfish server

Tags: tomcat, servlets, glassfish

I'm building a new project using Tomcat 2.5. After i migrate all the class and jsp file into existing project in glassfish server 2.5, there is no problem in my jsp file. i got 404 error only when calling my servlet, in which, it can't find my servlet class.  i already added below line in my web.xml :

```
  <servlet>
    <description/>
    <display-name>ReportServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ReportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.raydar.report.ReportServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReportServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/grade</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

is there anything that i need to configure in the glassfish server instead of just changing the web.xml? someone please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is your servlet depolyed in the package you defined? Is any exception thrown?

Comment: yes i have deployed it in the package defined. i got no exception, only the 404 error..

Comment: Which url are you accessing? I should be like http://localhost:[port]/[App-Name]/grade. Hit http://localhost:4848/ -> "Applications" and see what your app context path looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the problem. Then i figure out my problem. Before migrating your project from Tomcat to Glassfish, it is very important to create **web.xml** in Configuration Files folder. So, create new Servlet in main package. Netbeans(in my case) can generate web.xml Configuration Files folder. Then copy all files from Tomcat server project to Glassfish server project. Then, write all servlet information in **web.xml** .

Its work for me. I guess it will be the same for you.